# Pandas - Sorting By Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame known as "df":

```
  x y
0 1 2
1 2 4
2 3 8
```

I am splitting it up into two frames, and then trying to merge back together:

```
df_1 = df[df['x']==1]  
df_2 = df[df['x']!=1]
```

My goal is to get it back in the same order, but when I concat, I am getting the following:

```
frames = [df_1, df_2]
solution = pd.concat(frames)
solution.sort_values(by='x', inplace=False)

  x y
1 2 4
2 3 8
0 1 2
```

The problem is I need the 'x' values to go back into the new dataframe in the same order that I extracted. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.loc` to specify the order you want.  Choose the original index.

```
solution.loc[df.index]
```

Or, if you trust the index values in each component, then

```
solution.sort_index()
```

[image]

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 8]], columns=['x', 'y'])

df_1 = df[df['x']==1]  
df_2 = df[df['x']!=1] 

frames = [df_1, df_2]
solution = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [14]: pd.concat([df_1, df_2.sort_values('y')])
Out[14]:
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  8
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sorting the solution using
`solution.sort_values(by='x', inplace=False)`
you need to specify inplace = True. That would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these assumptions on `df`:

1. Columns `x` and `y` are note necessarily ordered.
2. The index is ordered.

Just order your result by index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 8]})
df_1 = df[df['x']==1]  
df_2 = df[df['x']!=1] 
frames = [df_2, df_1]
solution = pd.concat(frames).sort_index()
```

Now, `solution` looks like this:

```
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  8
```